# How to get font metrics for the system clock in the Windows Explorer notification area?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray, windows-explorer

I'm working on the UI control that will be displayed in the taskbar notification area and I was thinking to match its font to the one used by the system clock:

[image]

But when I try to get its font as such:

```
HWND hWndTaskBar = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, L"Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
if(hWndTaskBar)
{
    HWND hWndNotify = ::FindWindowEx(hWndTaskBar, NULL, L"TrayNotifyWnd", NULL);
    if(hWndNotify)
    {
        HWND hClockWnd = ::FindWindowEx(hWndNotify, NULL, L"TrayClockWClass", NULL);
        if(hClockWnd)
        {
            HFONT hFontClock = (HFONT)::SendMessage(hClockWnd, WM_GETFONT, NULL, NULL);
            if(hFontClock)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result for `HFONT` is NULL.

Any idea how to get it otherwise?

Comment: No API for that, and if there was then it wouldn't involve hacking away at implementation details.

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to get the visual theme.  You can then query the theme for the font.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: You know I had such a hard time making those theme APIs work in the past that I'm not sure that I'll get it going now. So I don't think your "marked as duplicate" is actually true. As a working solution I was able to find this key `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` and [`IconFont`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960276.aspx) binary value in it, that is one-to-one `LOGFONT` struct, that seem to match what is used on the system tray. That metric is also updated according to current DPI settings.

Comment: @c00000fd: Grabbing values from the registry is generally unsupported and likely to break as the OS evolves.  The particular value you're looking at is probably the source of the LOGFONT you get from SetParametersInfo when you ask for the non-client metrics, which has a high probability of being the same as the clock's font, but it's not really _how_ you get the clock's font metrics.  I'll vote to re-open, and perhaps somebody will answer with sample code based on the clock's visual style.

Comment: Unfortunately the Themes documentation is some of the worst documentation Microsoft have ever produced.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: True in theory, not true in practice. Microsoft would be on a hot seat with backwards compatibility if they change things. Thus it's not in their interest (even though the docs say it.)